# Como hacer que me funcione la función de redimensionar el Tbody de mi tabla en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

**Bueno tengo una `función` que me dibuja una tabla con dimensiones diferentes**

**Aqui tengo un ejecutable:**
https://codepen.io/mauricio_85/pen/rNLoLqd

***la consola como pueden observar a la primera me bota bien con numeros pero cuando ya escribo en el input un 6 o cualquier otro numero me bota [] vacio.***

*Esto es una `función` que lo que hace es dibujar y ajustar acuerdo a los datos que hay en el `tbody`*

```
function valorjs() {
            $(document).ready(function () {

                $('.bz-table-body thead').clone().appendTo('.bz-table-head');

                var Twidths = [];

                $('.bz-table-body thead th').each(
                    function () {
                        $(this).css('width', $(this).outerWidth());
                    });

                $('.bz-table-body thead th').each(
                    function () {
                        Twidths.push($(this).outerWidth());
                    });

               console.log(Twidths);

                // ... and now update widths on thead
                $('.bz-table-head colgroup col').each(
                    function (i, val) {
                        $(this).css('width', Twidths[i]);
                    });
                $('.bz-table-body colgroup col').each(
                    function (i, val) {
                        $(this).css('width', Twidths[i]);
                    });


                $('.bz-table-head').css('table-layout', 'fixed');
                $('.bz-table-body').css('table-layout', 'fixed');

                $(".bz-table-body__wrapper").scroll(function () {
                    var scrolltrack = $(".bz-table-body__wrapper").scrollLeft();
                    //console.log(scrolltrack);
                    $(".bz-table-head").css({
                        "left": -scrolltrack
                    });
                });

                $('.bz-table-body thead').remove();


            });
        }
```

*Funciona cuando por primera vez la pagina web es dibujada pero tengo una `función` buscador lo que realiza es traerme nueva información pero en aquí la función de dibujar el `tbody` ya no funciona y me devuelve un array vacio*

**cuando dibuja la tabla me devuelve lo siguiente por primera vez**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero aquí tengo una función que lo que hace es traerme nueva información con lo que solicite y aquí ya no me funciona la `función` `valorjs`

```
$("#buscar").keyup(function () {
            /*console.log( "Handler for .keypress() called." );
            /*var pal = $('#buscar').val();
            console.log($('#buscar').val());*/
            var x = $(this).val();
            fetch_data_buscar(x);           
           // console.log(x);
        });
        //Buscador 1
        function fetch_data_buscar (pal) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "fetch_buscar.php?pal=" + pal,
                success: function (data) {
                   
                    $('tbody').html(data);
                    valorjs();
                }
                
            });
            
        }
```

*aqui es donde al cambiar con `keyup` en un input me trae la información pero ya no redimensiona el `tbody`  y en la consola me bota array vacio*

**como la sig. imagen**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Aqui tengo un ejecutable**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  
fetch_data();

  $("#buscar").keyup(function () {
              var x = $(this).val();
              fetch_data_buscar(x);           
   });
  function fetch_data_buscar (pal) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/" + pal,
      success: function (data) {

        $('tbody').html(data);
        valorjs();
      }

    });

  }


  function fetch_data() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/3",
      success: function (data) {
        $('tbody').html(data);
        console.log( data );
        valorjs();
      }
    });
  }
  
  function valorjs() {
    $(document).ready(function () {

      $('.bz-table-body thead').clone().appendTo('.bz-table-head');

      var Twidths = [];

      $('.bz-table-body thead th').each(
        function () {
          $(this).css('width', $(this).outerWidth());
        });

      $('.bz-table-body thead th').each(
        function () {
          Twidths.push($(this).outerWidth());
        });

      console.log(Twidths);

      // ... and now update widths on thead
      $('.bz-table-head colgroup col').each(
        function (i, val) {
          $(this).css('width', Twidths[i]);
        });
      $('.bz-table-body colgroup col').each(
        function (i, val) {
          $(this).css('width', Twidths[i]);
        });


      $('.bz-table-head').css('table-layout', 'fixed');
      $('.bz-table-body').css('table-layout', 'fixed');

      $(".bz-table-body__wrapper").scroll(function () {
        var scrolltrack = $(".bz-table-body__wrapper").scrollLeft();
        //console.log(scrolltrack);
        $(".bz-table-head").css({
          "left": -scrolltrack
        });
      });

      $('.bz-table-body thead').remove();


    });
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  padding:50px;
}
```

```html
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

    
    <table class="bz-table bz-table-head">
      <colgroup>
        <col>
        <col>
        <col>
        <col>
      </colgroup>
    </table>

  <div class="bz-table-body__wrapper">

    <table class="bz-table bz-table-body">
      <colgroup>
        <col>
        <col>
        <col>
        <col>
      </colgroup>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>test</th>
          <th>test</th>
          <th>test</th>
          <th>test</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      </tbody>
    </table>
   </div>
     
    
    

    


    
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
       <input  class="form-control"       id="buscar" name="buscar" placeholder="ingrese palabra a buscar" > </input>
     </div>
  </div>


  

   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
```

**Bueno en el ejecutable como pueden ver al iniciar o ejecutar aparece numeros:**

1. El primero son el datos
2. El segundo ya es la dimension que genera la `función valorjs()`
3. Pero al escribir en el input ya no dimensiona osea que deja de
   funcionar `la función valorjs()`
4. Para ejecutar entren en pantalla completa y escriban 4 0 algun numero
   en el input y les aparecer un  array []

Alguna solución gracias .

Comment: Quita el evento `$(document).ready(function () {` de tu función, eso genera que ya no se vuelva a ejecutar, por que estará esperando el evento ready de el documento que ya se genero cuando cargo,

Comment: no me funciono jejej